# how can I remove prototype fields from an object?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

How can I remove prototype fields from an object besides via this method ?

```
const input = {foo: 'bar', __proto__: {unwanted: 'things'}}
expect(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input))).toEqual({foo: 'bar'})  // true
// this works but is there a cleaner way ?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Its never a good idea to remove the `__proto__` of an object. It has all properties that make it an object, you should instead consider using `hasOwnProperty`

Answer (score 2):

it depends what you trying to achieve, but I would generally recommend `.hasOwnProperty` for checking whether the field is a prototype field

reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Object.create` and pass to it `null` which will create clean object without `prototype` property, then you can create your properties for that object, but note that you can't use `Object.prototype` methods like `hasOwnProperty(), toString(), valueOf()` and so on

```js
const input = Object.create(null);
input.foo = 'bar';
console.log(input);
```

Comment: Does this create a deep or shallow copy?

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense it creates a whole empty object like so `{}` without any properties including prototype too

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good recursive solution to fix if already stored and objects need a rewrite:

```js
/**
 * Remove __proto__ entries from array/object
 * @param {Any} obj
 * @return {Any}
 */
const stripProto = (obj) => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj = obj.map(item => stripProto(item)).filter(item => {
      return String(item) !== '__proto__';
    });
  } else if (typeof obj === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj)) {
    for (const key in obj) {
      if (String(obj[key]) === '__proto__' || key === '__proto__') {
        delete obj[key];
      } else {
        obj[key] = stripProto(obj[key]);
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
};
```